# Does there exist a pole on the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, singularity

> Show that a power series $\sum _{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$ where $a_n \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty  $
>   cannot have a pole on the unit circle.
>
> > Is the statement true with the hypothesis that $(a_n )$ is a bounded sequence?

As $a_n\to 0$ so the radius of convergence of the power series is greater than or equal to $1$. So the power series converges on the unit disc and hence defines an analytic function say $f$  therein.

Hence the power series can't have any isolated singularity on the unit disc and hence neither can have a pole.

Though I feel the second answer is **NO** ,I am unable to find a counter-example

I would have been happy to find some help from someone.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17932/about-the-limit-of-the-coefficient-ratio-for-a-power-series-over-complex-numbers

Comment: Don't mix unit circle and unit disc.

Comment: Please ... it's $\sum a_n z^n$

Comment: @zhw. Good point, but it would have been quicker to edit the question than to post your comment... :)

Comment: This first part is much subtler than that: A series with your condition _can_ have a singularity _other than a pole_ on the unit circle. Consider for example $$z+\frac12z^2+\frac13z^2+\frac14z^4+\cdots = -\log(1-z)$$ which has a _branch point_ at $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show is this: Let $D$ be the open unit disc. Suppose $z_0\in \partial D, r > 0,$ and $f$ is analytic on $\{z|<1\} \cup D(z_0,r).$ Suppose further that in $D,$ $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, with $a_n \to 0.$ Then $f$ does not have a pole at $z_0.$

Here's a hint: WLOG, $z_0=1.$ Show $\lim_{x\to 1^-}(1-x)f(x)=0.$ Could any function with a pole satisfy this?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 1 ^{-}}(1-x)f(x)=(1-x)(a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n)$ ;How could you say that this limit is zero

Comment: With each $a_n=1,$ the limit is $1.$ Now what do you think happens if $a_n \to 0?$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the constant sequence $a_n=1$.

(I assume the question means assume $a_n$ bounded instead of the assumption $a_n\to0$.)